# Unity c# convert string to param name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need to convert a string to a param name to take his value, but i **don't** need to use the **dictionary** or **ref**, something like this

```
bool boolean;

void Start()
{
    boolean = false;
    Debug.Log("After = " + boolean);
    changeBool("boolean");
    Debug.Log("BeFore = " + boolean); // It will be true
}

void changeBool(string variableName)
{
    
}
```

Please, help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)?

Comment: This is a bad idea and you should consider some other approach. It requires users to know the names of internal variables in your code. You're probably looking for an interface (guaranteed functionality across classes). Best case this is spaghetti to document and maintain, worst case is you open yourself up to some serious vulnerabilities.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to do that to whrite less code, because i need to memorize the navigation of a menu dinamically.
I search another solution.

Answer (score 1):

As vernou already said, you can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

```
void changeBool(string variableName)
{
    // Check for field existance, you can also log it
    var fieldInfo = GetType().GetField(variableName);
    if (fieldInfo == null) return;

    // Check if variable is a bool type and get the current value
    var oldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
    if (oldValue is not bool oldBoolean) return;
    
    fieldInfo.SetValue(this, !oldBoolean);
}
```

**But be careful** if the variable name comes from a dangerous source, it can become a vulnerability in your code
Someone can enter a deliberately false variable name
I recommend redesigning your code

Comment: The last thing you want to add to a _game_ is **reflection**.

Comment: @MickyD, to almost any project, unless you are developing a large framework and reflection is absolutely necessary. Otherwise it's always bad smell of code. But yeah, I just answered this guy direct question

Comment: is this line correct ? `   if (oldValue is not bool oldBoolean) return;`